# Unique Fact. Irr. $\iff$ Irr. is prime, proof.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am writing a proof of the following theorem:

> In a domain in which factorization into irreducible is possible:
>
> Factorization is unique $\iff$ Every irreducible is prime.

I essentially have two questions about the method:

1. For the converse, in the book that I study (*Algebraic number Theory and Fermat's last theorem*, by David Tall and Stewart Ian), . I have an issue with that, as i don't really understand the structure of that induction. To me, it feels like a "backward induction". Is my way of writing it wrong?
2. is there a point in $\implies$ which isn't correct?

**Proof from THE BOOK** (Pardon my Eötvös reference) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeFC0.png

**My Version (converse):**

$\impliedby$: Suppose there are two Factorizations into (prime) irreducibles of an element $$u_1\prod_i^mp_i=x=u_2\prod_j^n q_j$$ We will show that $n = m$ and that there is a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that $p_i$ and $q_{\pi(i)}$ are associates.
Suppose $m \geq 1$, by assumption $p_m|(u_2 \prod_j^n q_j) \implies p_m|u_2 \lor p_m|q_j$, the first case would imply that $p_m$ is a unit, which can't be: The second case must hold for some $j$, which we renumber such that $j = n$. Now, both must be associates, so we have
$$u_1 p_m \prod_i^{m-1}p_i =u_2 (u_mp_m) \prod_j^{n-1} q_j \implies u_1  \prod_i^{m-1}p_i = (u_2u_m) \prod_j^{n-1} q_j  $$
We can repeat this step until we reach $m = 0 \lor n = 0$ and for $m \neq n$, a contradiction arises.

$\implies$: Suppose that factorization into irreducibles is unique and let $p$ be an irreducible that divides $x = ab$. We have $a = u_1 \prod_i a_i$ and $b = u_2 \prod_j b_j$. Since $p|x$, we also have $x = cp \implies ab = cp $ with $c = u_3 \prod_k c_k$. We have $u_1 u_2 = u_3$ and we are left with $p \prod_k c_k = \prod_i a_i \prod_j b_j$ with every term irreducible and by uniqueness, $p$ must divide either some $a_i$ or some $b_j$ and is therefore prime.

Comment: Replacing "backwards induction" by a minimality assumption usually simplifies such proofs.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer And minimality assumption would go more in my direction, correct? (If i undersand what you mean by minimality, my proof would go like this : suppose $n \neq m$ and wlog $m>n$n, we take $p_m$ associate of $q_n$ and "reduce". There is a minimal $n$ associated to $m=0$ and we get a contradiction. So $m=n$ and our process of rearranging grants us our $\pi \in S_n$.

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by "backwards" induction, i.e. what does "backwards" mean here?

Comment: Btw, your paraphrase of the proof in the book omits key details. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeFC0.png) is the actual proof. It's always best to quote it *exactly*.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you! I guess i don't understand the structure of the Induction then.

Comment: See my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of $\impliedby$ is by standard induction, though you rephrased it slightly probably giving rise to your confusion.

The induction hypothesis here is that any factorisation into $m-1$ irreducible elements is unique from which we then deduce that a factorisation into $m$ element has to be unique as well. For this we start with a factorisation into $m$ elements and argue that we can "get rid of" (see *Bill Dubuque*'s comment) one of the irreducible factors. This reduces us to a factorisation into $m-1$ elements for which we know that the result holds.

The base case for the induction is the emtpy factorisation, i.e. a unit. As the a product of ring elements is a unit iff all its constitutes are units this is clear.

Your proof of $\implies$ is correct.

Comment: We "get rid of" of $p_m$ by *cancelling* it on both sides (absorbing the unit $q_n/p_m$ into the unit $u_2$), leaving a smaller length $=(m-1)$  factorization, whose uniqueness follows by induction. It's the same as the ubiquitous proof in $\Bbb N$ except that we work with primes *up to unit factors*, i.e. we inductively match up *associate* (vs. equal) primes on both sides, via Euclid's lemma. To avoid the pesky unit factors we could instead work with principal ideals $(p),$ where $(p)=(q)$ iff $\,p\approx q\,$ (are associate).

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I see. The wording is far from optimal. I'll put the "get rid of" part in quotation marks and refer to your comment!

Comment: @BillDubuque I can't help but wonder, is my approach wrong? I don't feel like it is, but I know the devil is in the detail and i know that my post isn't the most rigoruous.

Comment: @Pastudent Your proof copies the book's proof except you replace the book's invocation of the inductive step ("by induction we may...) by a less precise sentence "We can repeat this step...".  To be rigorous you need to say *precisely* how we can repeat it, i.e. you need to precisely formulate the inductive hypothesis and then precisely show how it applies. It seems that you have some difficulty comprehending the inductive step.